# Placing an input of type password in prompt box

Tags: javascript

Hello guys 
I know that is probably a stupid question but i had to be sure after all.
Can i add an input of type password in a prompt box?
prompt box is a one of javascript's Popup boxes.(Alert,Confirm and Prompt)

Comment: What exactly is a "prompt box"?

Comment: Jon: var res = prompt('Are you sure','Default value')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't.

The popup is browser controlled and can't be changed.

As the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) shows, you can only supply a message and default text.

---

You can use javascript to create your own overlay that simulates a prompt popup.

See the jQuery UI [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for ideas and examples.

Answer (score 6):

If you literally mean the [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:window.prompt) function, you can't. What you can do instead is pop up a `div` or similar above the main content of your page (using absolute positioning and a `z-index` value) and put the password box in there.

More in the various answers to these questions:

- [How to have a JQUERY POPUP window by using only JQUERY (without other extra JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407286/how-to-have-a-jquery-popup-window-by-using-only-jquery-without-other-extra-js)
- [Making a Javascript Yes/No Confirmation Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958057/making-a-javascript-yes-no-confirmation-box)

There are a variety of libraries you can use that will do the hard work for you (not that it's *that* hard, but still). If you're already using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries), you may find that there's a plug-in designed for use with that library ([jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) for jQuery, for instance). If not, there are plenty of stand-alone implementations. Look for "light box" or "lightweight window" or "JavaScript dialog box", etc.

Note that any of these will require a bit of a change to the logic of your code, since `prompt` brings the browser and your script to a screeching halt until the prompt is dismissed by the user, whereas this mechanism of flying an element over the top of the content is, by its nature, asynchronous.

Comment: @Oded,@T.J Crowder:Actually both your answers are awesome i don't know which one i should vote for.

Comment: @Sarah: LOL, why choose? Vote 'em both up! (Just kidding.) I don't think mine is the accepted answer on either of those questions (one of them doesn't *have* an accepted answer, grrr), but I figured those questions and everyone's answers to them would help.

Comment: Ok don't worry i might accept the answer for Oded but just a note for all the people who visit this page T.J Crowder answer was awesome and helpful too.Ah and i voted it up.