# How can I change the password input prompt in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I change the type of password input prompt in ASP.NET? I have a prompt that I wrote in JavaScript. When a user types his password, it shows up as `****`. Can I determine the length of password here?

Comment: are you using the javascript prompt function? answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508077/placing-an-input-of-type-password-in-prompt-box

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built in js prompt, you're probably going to want to use jQuery to create a pretty, styled div that will function like a dialog instead. There is an HTML example of that here (you'll have to adapt it a little to make it all work with ASP, but that won't take long):
http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/login-box-modal-dialog-window-with-css-and-jquery/

Once you have a "prompt" that is in fact just a div that is appearing like an overlay, you can stick this inside it:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="20" />
```