# How do I make my .js password into asterisks?

Tags: javascript, html, password-protection

I have a basic JS code for a password, but whenever I type into the text box, it shows what has been typed, not the normal asterisks that are shown in password boxes. My code follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
Enter Password
</title>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var password = "THE LIST";
var x = prompt("Enter in the password "," ");
if (x == password) {
  window.location = "index.html";
}
else {
window.location = "bad.htm";
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I made this for fun, I'm not stupid enough to use it for real protection.

Comment: There's no way to use `prompt()` for password input. Use an HTML input with `type="password"`.

Comment: You can't style a javascript prompt like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508077/placing-an-input-of-type-password-in-prompt-box

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508077/placing-an-input-of-type-password-in-prompt-box

Comment: You can though, open a new window and use `.htaccess` to generate a prompt with a password field. After success, return some value back to your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in a prompt. A prompt is a feature of the browser / OS that is sandboxed. If you want control you need to do it in HTML:

```
<input type="password" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use: `<input type="password">`.