# asterisk instead the real data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to build a kind of "game" for my home work the mission is to give the first player to choose a number and the second player need to guesses the number .
there is one problem that when the first player typing the number it is reveal to the second user so my question is how to make a asterisk that the other player will not see the data(this is the main mission on this exercise)?

this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var num1 = parseInt(prompt('Enter your number.'));
    var num2 = parseInt(prompt('try gusses the number'));
    var theBiggerNumber = (num1==num2)?alert('you win'):alert('you lost');
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508077/placing-an-input-of-type-password-in-prompt-box

Comment: you can't change the look of `prompt()`, you'll need to create a different place for player 1 to type, such as `<input type='password' />`

Comment: always use === instead of == ([more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons))

Comment: Look at the solution of your homework below in answer...would that suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompt is always used for reading user inputs...

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

You can't use it for some custom data type (in this case password). Consider implementing in with html and js:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bb3sS/

HTML:

```
Player 1<input id='1' type='password'></input><br/>
Player 2<input id='2' type='password'></input><br/>
<button onclick='whoWon()'>Who won</button>
```

JS:

```
whoWon = function () {
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('1').value);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('2').value);

    (num1==num2)?alert('you win'):alert('you lost');
}
```